# Getting rid of black shadow/stain in toilet caused by interaction of iron sponge with anticalc + toilet gel with bleach

Tags: toilet, porcelain

There was a lot of stains down in the puddle (?) of my toilet and toilet gel (that has bleach/javel in it, [this product](https://www.wekagroup.be/en/mr-propre-liquid-with-bleach-3in1-6x1l-xml-369-1271.html)) and anticalc (the spray to wash lime scale off) and toilet brush didn't help. So I scrubbed it with an iron sponge. Now there is a shadow in the puddle on the porcelain which doesn't go off with anything.

I have dried the puddle (yes, taken the water out by hand) and washed with high consentrations of those liquids and the toilet brush but the shadow is still there. What can I do? And I have almost one day before returning the room.

([This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjrVC.jpg))

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is your toilet really, really, really old? I've never seen a modern toilet accumulate stains like you describe. Might be time for a replacement (that uses less water, too).

Comment: @isherwood It actually is 20+ years old, and the landlord insists it can be cleaned. Spring was a typo for sponge, edited, and javel is apparently the French/Dutch name of bleach (I got it in Belgium). I included a link to the product and to the photo of the toilet.

Comment: Iron sponge? Does that mean steel wool?

Comment: Try Coca-Cola. Fill the "puddle" with Coke and let it sit for a couple of hours. The acid might do the trick.

Comment: @isherwood maybe I'm using the wrong English term for it. The kind of "sponge" which is like filaments of curly iron and used in washing the dishes ([this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51LPSg3qfZL._SY355_.jpg), I looked up steel wool and it was a bit different—not like the thing used for dishes.)

Comment: @Nickoloff I'll buy coke tomorrow and try that, thanks.

Comment: You can get a pumice stone attached to a stick and it cleans metal stains from porcelain.  Amazon sells one called "Hard Water Wand Pumice Stone Toilet Bowl Cleaner, Toilet Wand"

Comment: Did you leave the lime scale remover in there for a couple of hours?  It didn't get there in seconds, and it won't remove in seconds.  You are chemically dissolving solid rock.  That certainly makes more sense than using Coke.  (Any soda would do, Pepsi, root beer, diet Dr Pepper, etc).

Comment: The problem may be two many harsh chemicals have been used over the years and the porcelain is etched , you may get it clean but it will stain again.

Comment: @GregNickoloff 1.5 liter of soda (Sprite-like one) and a couple of hours and brushing helped sufficiently!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Iron OUT](https://summitbrands.com/iron-out-rust-stain-removers/powder/) or similar cleaners with sodium hydrosulfite and/or sodium metabisulfite, which *reduce* iron and manganese stains, rather than *bleach* (Javel) which does the opposite. Place a paper towel over the stain and soak in the remover, so that it does not run off immediately. Let it sit for some *hours* and repeat as needed.

**Do not use** abrasives such as pumice, or hydrofluoric acid (HF), as in Whink Rust Stain Remover, which will remove the stain, but will also *permanently damage the china bowl*... which your landlord may ask you to replace.